# How does GCC pass arguments/returns in assembly code?

Tags: c, function, assembly, return, call

I have a bit of C code that uses Assembly inlines. Supposed there is a simple function like

```
int f(int arg) {...}
```

declared in the C code but implemented in assembly.
How does GCC pass the arguments and the return values between the C and ASM code? Is it stack push/pop? Registers?

The makefile uses options

```
gccc -Wall -g -std=c99 -pedantic -g
```

Comment: This depends on the [ABI of the platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface).

Comment: Its x86_64 architecture. Would cdelc calling convention be the default for gcc compiler? @zx485

Comment: @ArekBulski No, the [SYS V x86_64 ABI](https://www.uclibc.org/docs/psABI-x86_64.pdf) is (unless you compile for x32 or x86). You can google it or search it here, there are plenty of QA about it.

Comment: @ArekBulski On x86_64, the exact calling convention depends on what operating system you are programming for.

Comment: Its compiled and runned on Ubuntu (linux).

Comment: (The answer there includes the function calling convention, as well as system-call convention.)

Comment: @ArekBulski In this case, see the documentation linked to by Margaret Bloom.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI) has a slightly simpler explanation of how that works.